# Is there a way to use '@' as the position of a substring within a nested function?

Tags: substring, oracle-apex, decode, substr

I'm trying to DECODE the email of employees to the Company's name of that email type by combining DECODE with SUBSTRING. For some odd reason, the result keeps giving me an error of invalid number but I've used the SUBSTR's position with non-numeric values(symbols such as @ before) but it is not working now.

Is there a way around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Invalid `substr` function usage. The 2nd parameter isn't a "string" but its **position** - use `instr` function to find it.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (email_add) as
  2    (select 'devisthemans56@gmail.com' from dual union all
  3     select 'turtleboy707@aol.com'     from dual union all
  4     select 'jazzlover1@yahoo.com'     from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select email_add,
  7    decode(substr(email_add, instr(email_add, '@') + 1),
  8               'gmail.com', 'Google',
  9               'yahoo.com', 'Yahoo',
 10               'aol.com'  , 'AOL',
 11                            'unknown'
 12          ) result
 13  from test;

EMAIL_ADD                RESULT
------------------------ -------
devisthemans56@gmail.com Google
turtleboy707@aol.com     AOL
jazzlover1@yahoo.com     Yahoo

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTR` takes a numeric value as argument to determine where to start. '@' is not a numeric value. To determine the position of the '@' sign use `INSTR`.

```
WITH emails (email) AS
(
  SELECT 'john.doe@gmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane.doe@aol.com' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT 
  CASE SUBSTR(email,INSTR(email,'@') + 1) 
    WHEN 'gmail.com' THEN 'google'
    WHEN 'aol.com' THEN 'aol'
    ELSE 'unknown'
   END CASE
  FROM emails;
```

I used a `CASE` statement instead of `DECODE`. It's a lot easier to read and has the same functionality.